# fwrite() c function writing extra bytes

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, fwrite, bmp

I'm using eclipse for c (Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0) Build id: 20200313-1211) and MinGW (version 0.6.3-pre-20170905-1).

I have been playing with `fwrite()` for the past few weeks, mainly creating BMP files, without any weird problems.

Something really strange is happening now that I do not understand at all: the resulting file has 2 extra bytes and thus the image is corrupted and can not be displayed.

- I have read the value that `fwrite()` returns and is equal to the size meant to write (384 both cases)
- I have checked the data of the pointer given to `fwrite()` and the internal `(FILE*)->_base` and both point to an address with the correct content, but different from what the generated file has.

And when deleting this 2 bytes, the image is perfectly readable (I use the software HxD).

This is the generated file, the 2 bytes are the `0D` before the two `0A 00 00 00` (which are the width and height) are these extra bytes that I don't have a clue where they come from, and because where are located, they offset all the other BMP header info and corrupt the image!

[Contents of the corrupted BMP file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BsH1.png)

The BMP is nothing fancy at all, just a 10x10px square with a grayscale gradient.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open the file in binary mode.

Comment: [creating .mid file: writing a '\n' causes '\r\n' in Windows](//stackoverflow.com/a/45849407)

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your code that you believe are related to the problem.  ( [mcve] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, thanks to everyone for your fast answers!

Indeed was the `\n`converted to `\r\n` issue. Creating the file as binary (`fopen(<>,"wb")`) has solved the issue!

Thanks tkausl and Johnny Mopp !
Thanks to everyone, you are amazing people!